# Concurrent access of AtomicMarkableReference compareandset method and get method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, java.util.concurrent

The `compareAndSet()` method of `AtomicMarkableReference` of Java works atomically. So, no two such methods can run concurrently on same object. However, if one of the thread is executing the `compareAndSet()` method and another one is executing the `get()` or `gerReference()` method concurrently on the same object, will these `get()` or `gerReference()` method be waiting (blocked) for the `compareAndSet()` method to be finished?

Comment: The [package summary JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) of `java.util.concurrent` explain the semantics of the atomic classes nicely. Basically, the operations are non-blocking, although it depends a bit on on the underlying hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `compareAndSet()` is a [CAS operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (which is implied by its name), so it's a non-blocking and two threads can call it concurrently, but the implementation guarantees the result to be correct.

It also means that both `get()` and `getReference()` are non-blocking operations either. They just read the values of volatile fields with no additional synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

No one of these two methods will be waiting for when the compareAndSet() method will be finished.

Look at its source code:

```
public V getReference() {
    return pair.reference;
}
public V get(boolean[] markHolder) {
    Pair<V> pair = this.pair;
    markHolder[0] = pair.mark;
    return pair.reference;
}

public boolean compareAndSet(V       expectedReference,
                             V       newReference,
                             boolean expectedMark,
                             boolean newMark) {
    Pair<V> current = pair;
    return
        expectedReference == current.reference &&
        expectedMark == current.mark &&
        ((newReference == current.reference &&
          newMark == current.mark) ||
         casPair(current, Pair.of(newReference, newMark)));
}

private boolean casPair(Pair<V> cmp, Pair<V> val) {
    return UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, pairOffset, cmp, val);
}
```

There is no any code to block a thread.

Please read [the description of the package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) of the class.

> Package java.util.concurrent.atomic
> A small toolkit of classes that support **lock-free** thread-safe programming on single variables.

It is lock-free algorithms. But it still may depends from your hardware